# ChatBot responder somente quando uma palavra específica estiver contida na frase

Tags: python, if, chatbot, response, telegram-bot

Estou criando um ChatBot no Telegram que pode responder a perguntas de usuários do grupo. O bot precisa de uma palavra-chave para começar a conversar. Essa palavra seria o seu nome, "Joker". Assim, somente quando a palavra Joker fosse mencionada em uma frase ele começaria a interagir com os usuários do grupo ou quando uma resposta fosse encaminhada a ele. Utilizando Python 3.7.4.

**Exemplo:**

> - **Usuário:** Acho que o Joker entende mais desse assunto
> - **Bot:** Que assunto?
> - **Usuário:** Sobre a matança de focas no sertão do Ceará, Joker.
> - **Bot:** Sobre o que você está falando?

Mas não tenho ideia de como implementar essa ação.

```
def respond(self, message):
    """
   Receive message from user and returns corresponding answer.
   """
    if len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
        top_answer = get_analysis(message)
        return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    elif re.search("Joker", message) or len(message) > 0:
        return self.comm.get_response(self.clean(message))
    else:
        return "Algo de errado não está certo"\
               " Digite /info para saber mais."
```

Comment: Você precisa ter uma lista de comandos predefinidos. Se você está buscando fazer algo como a assistente da Google (que responde inúmeras perguntas formuladas das mais diferentes formas, além de ser tolerante a erros), tenha um orçamento de milhões de dólares primeiro.

Comment: Eu já possuo um arquivo .yml com inúmeras perguntas e respostas predefinidas. Ele não precisa ser tolerante a erros. Não é algo assim "astronômico" ao estilo Assistente do Google. O ChatBot em si, funciona sem problemas, respondendo as perguntas ou dando uma resposta padrão quando não tem uma resposta em seu banco de dados. Mas, a intenção é a de ele responder no grupo, somente quando o nome dele fosse mencionado em uma frase e não, ficar respondendo a qualquer mensagem que é enviada no grupo, como é o que acontece.

Answer (score 2):

O que eu percebo no seu código, é que a primeira condição não verifica se existe "joker" na mensagem. Presumo que ele está resondendo sempre "Hm, você está falando sobre ..."

Para corrigir somente isto, mude a primeira condição para:

```
if 'Joker' in message and len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
```

Caso você não entenda Python, a condição verifica:

1. Se 'Joker' está na mensagem
2. Se a mensagem contém mais de **50** caracteres
3. (Presumo eu) se você excedeu a sua cota do IBM Watson

---

Do jeito que está, joker precisa ter a primeira letra maiúscula para disparar o código. Suponho que o ideal seria que ele respondesse a qualquer combinação de minúsculas e maiúsculas.

Neste caso, este é o código:

```
def respond(self, message):
    """
    Receive message from user and returns corresponding answer.
    """
    if re.search("joker", message, re.IGNORECASE):
        joker_na_mensagem = True
    else:
        joker_na_mensagem = False

    if joker_na_mensagem and len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
        top_answer = get_analysis(message)
        return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    elif joker_na_mensagem and len(message.strip()) == len('joker'):
        return "Algo de errado não está certo. Digite /info para saber mais."
    elif joker_na_mensagem:
        return self.comm.get_response(self.clean(message))
```

Edit 1: alterei a segunda condição, onde (presumo) o bot iria responder a qualquer mensagem que tivesse mais que 0 caracteres, independentemente de ser mencionado. Eliminei o requisito dos caracteres, pois, se 'Joker' está na mensagem, quer dizer que ela é maior que 0 caracteres.

Edit 2: alterei a última condição. Agora, a função só retorna a mensagem de erro caso alguém mencione o bot e não diga mais nada. Ou seja:

> Usuário: Joker
>   Bot: Algo de errado não está certo [...]

Edit 3: altera a ordem das condições, pois a segunda condição anulava a terceira.

Comment: Como os caracteres foram insuficientes no comentário, coloquei como uma resposta abaixo.

Comment: Então, @SeuMadruga, eu estou utilizando o Python 3.7.4. Atualizei o código. O Bot persiste em reagir a qualquer mensagem enviada ao grupo. Isso parece ser coisa do Chaves. Tinha que ser o Chaves.

Comment: Houve um progresso.O Bot reage como erro a qualquer mensagem que não contenha Joker na frase e retorna uma das respostas predefinidas a perguntas que ele ainda não aprendeu.
Usuário: Olá

Bot: Algo de errado não está certo Digite /info para saber mais.

Usuário: Olá joker

Bot: Não compreendi, você pode me falar como eu deveria ter respondido?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot/application.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bot.communication import Communication
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\bot\communication.py", line 67
    joker_na_mensagem = True
                    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @Jacob erro de identação. Tenta agora.

Comment: Agora acontece o seguinte:

File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\bot\communication.py", line 74
    return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: @Jacob Aparentemente, não há nada de errado. Você mexeu na identação? Eu já corrigi. Copia de novo e vê se funciona.

Comment: Não aparece mais nenhum erro. Porém, o Bot responde com "None" para mensagens que não contenha "Joker". E as que contém Joker na frase, ele responde com uma das respostas predefinidas, de que ele ainda não aprendeu. Não sei se seria possível, mas ele responder com as respostas já predefinidas. Tipo, que ele compreendesse a pergunta, ignorando o Joker na frase. O Joker na frase, faz com que ele não saiba dar uma resposta dentre todas as possíveis cadastradas. Desculpe se parecer confuso.

Comment: @Jacob é possível, mas está fora do escopo desta pergunta. Faça outra pergunta e elabore esta questão, e me avise aqui.

Comment: Então @SeuMadruga. Postei a nova pergunta.