# ChatBot não compreendendo frases cadastradas

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot, response

Estou desenvolvendo um ChatBot chamado "Joker" para utilização em um grupo do Telegram. O Bot deve responder apenas se o seu nome (Joker) for citado em uma frase, do contrário, ele deve permanecer "calado", sem interferir na conversa do grupo. Porém, ele "desperta" e responde com um valor nulo, "None" à qualquer mensagem enviada ao grupo. Com a palavra Joker contida na frase, o Bot não está compreendendo as perguntas predefinidas, cadastradas em seu treinamento e  responde com uma das respostas padrões à perguntas ainda não aprendidas.

> - **User:** Bom dia, pessoal!
> - **Bot:** None
> - **User:** Bom dia, Joker
> - **Bot:** Desculpa, mas não entendi sua mensagem.

```
def respond(self, message):
    """
    Receive message from user and returns corresponding answer.
    """
    if re.search("joker", message, re.IGNORECASE):
        joker_na_mensagem = True
    else:
        joker_na_mensagem = False

    if joker_na_mensagem and len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
        top_answer = get_analysis(message)
        return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    elif joker_na_mensagem and len(message.strip()) == len("joker"):
        return "Algo de errado não está certo. 
                Digite /info para saber mais."
    elif joker_na_mensagem:
        return self.comm.get_response(self.clean(message))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChatBot responder somente quando uma palavra específica estiver contida na frase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427775/chatbot-responder-somente-quando-uma-palavra-espec%c3%adfica-estiver-contida-na-frase)

Comment: A pergunta citada, é minha e possui um contexto diferente, não se encaixando na resposta que procuro. Elaborei melhor a pergunta para uma melhor compreensão.

Comment: Deveria editar a repostar anterior corrigindo a pergunta e não duplicando

Comment: Essa não é uma duplicata. A pergunta atual foge do propósito da pergunta original. Fui aconselhado por um usuário que estava me ajudando, a elaborar uma nova pergunta. Por esse motivo, eu não editei a anterior e fiz essa pergunta.

Comment: O usuário te orientou certo, porém se a pergunta original fugia do que estava a buscar, era apenas necessário elaborar uma nova pergunta e editar a anterior e não criar perguntas duplicadas só por que não obteve a reposta que esperava.

Answer (score 0):

Este código deverá remover 'joker' da mensagem a ser analisada.

```
def respond(self, message):
    """
    Receive message from user and returns corresponding answer.
    """
    if re.search("joker", message, re.IGNORECASE):
        joker_na_mensagem = True
    else:
        joker_na_mensagem = False

    mensagem_sem_joker = re.sub(r'\bjoker\b', '', message, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    # remove espaços duplicados
    mensagem_sem_joker = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', mensagem_sem_joker)

    if joker_na_mensagem and len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
        top_answer = get_analysis(mensagem_sem_joker)
        return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    elif joker_na_mensagem and len(message.strip()) == len("joker"):
        return "Algo de errado não está certo." \
               "Digite /info para saber mais."
    elif joker_na_mensagem:
        return self.comm.get_response(self.clean(mensagem_sem_joker))
```

Quanto à resposta `None`, você precisa editar o seu código, de forma que caso a função `respond` retorne `None`, você não repasse esse valor ao usuário, pois o `None` significa que não há resposta para aquela mensagem, provavelmente porque ela não foi direcionada ao bot.

Como não tenho acesso ao restante do código, não posso corrigir isto para você.

---

**Edit**

No código que você forneceu via Dropbox, há o seguinte trecho no arquivo `bot/application.py`:

```
def text_message(self, bot, update):
    self.send_type_action(bot, update)

    if not self.check_for_emotion(update):
        message = update.effective_message.text
        update.effective_message.reply_text(
            str(self.comm.respond(message))
        )
    return 0
```

Creio que esta seja a razão para o bot estar respondendo as mensagens com `None`. Este trecho de código está chamando `update.effective_message.reply_text` independentemente do que foi retornado pela função `respond`.

Para corrigir isto, substitua todo o trecho acima pelo seguinte código:

```
def text_message(self, bot, update):
    self.send_type_action(bot, update)

    if not self.check_for_emotion(update):
        message = update.effective_message.text
        resposta = self.comm.respond(message)
        if resposta:
            update.effective_message.reply_text(resposta)
    return 0
```

O que este código faz, é verificar se a função `respond` retornou algo. 
Caso sim, chama a função `reply_text` com o resultado.
Como a função `respond` só retorna `string` ou `None`, a conversão de tipos feita pelo `str` é desnecessária e foi removida.

*Obs: percebi que você estava copiando errado. Por isso, os erros de sintaxe.

A estrutura de uma função python é da forma que eu escrevi. Jamais alinhe o corpo de uma função à primeira linha dela.*

Comment: @Jacob este erro diz que eu referenciei mensagem_sem_joker antes de criá-lo, porém, eu não fiz isso. Acho que você pode ter alterado a formatação do código. Python é muito estrito na formatação do código. Copie como eu fiz e tente novamente. Quando ao código na íntegra, você me deu um link público. Este link só funciona para o dono do arquivo. Para compartilhar, você deve tornar a pasta pública e copiar o link público.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot/application.py", line 19, in <module>
    from bot.communication import Communication
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\bot\communication.py", line 81
    return f"Hmm, você está falando sobre {top_answer}"
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Código:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nm1otj1xbc1nsp5/AAAMKD9srT2nHLLVVHtNxYnfa?dl=0

Comment: @Jacob Atualizei.

Comment: Fiz tudo certinho como me indicou. Sem alterar a formatação do código. Uma parte da mensagem de erro:

File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\messagehandler.py", line 169, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "bot/application.py", line 166, in text_message
    update.effective_message.reply_text(resposta)

Comment: Só mesmo analisando o código completo para compreender melhor o que acontece. Cada momento aparece um erro diferente. Se você tiver disposição e paciência. Não quero tomar o seu tempo, afinal, você tem me ajudado demais. O código original em que me baseio, se encontra aqui:

[link](https://github.com/IEEEComputerSocietyUNB/ProjetoChatbot)

Comment: @Jacob insira o erro completo

Comment: telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - An uncaught error was raised while processing the update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\messagehandler.py", line 169, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "bot/application.py", line 166, in text_message
    update.effective_message.reply_text(resposta)

Comment: File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\message.py", line 455, in reply_text
    return self.bot.send_message(self.chat_id, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 65, in decorator
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 90, in decorator
    result = self._request.post(url, data, timeout=kwargs.get('timeout'))

Comment: File "E:\01 - Projeto ChatBot Master\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 308, in post
    body=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

Comment: File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Statement is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Jacob Você corrigiu a formatação que estava errada? Receio que você tenha introduzido muitos erros no seu código, pois isto não parece estar relacionado a minha solução para esta pergunta.

Comment: Sim @seu-madruga. Tudo certo, conforme você postou e indicou. Cheguei a deletar a pasta venv, imaginando algum arquivo que possa ter sido corrompido, depois reinstalei o Python novamente, mas continua na mesma. Não sei se serve de ajuda, mas acontece o seguinte. Qualquer mensagem que é enviada ao grupo, sempre aparece, Joker está escrevendo. Como se ele estivesse "escutando", mas sem responder. E ele reage da seguinte maneira.
>User: Olá
>User: Olá Joker
>User: Joker
>Bot: Algo de errado não está certo. Digite /info para saber mais.

Comment: Como eu disse, este erro não parece mais estar relacionado com a pergunta. Também não faz sentido eu olhar o código de onde você copiou, pois você o modificou e são grandes as chances de que você introduziu estes erros. Eu assisti até onde pude, mas agora você deve averiguar os erros que estão aparecendo e formular novas perguntas. Seja muito detalhista nas suas perguntas, se não, vou acabar desenvolvendo tudo para você. Este não é o propósito do site. Como pode ver, há muitos votos negativos, pois falta informações, códigos completos e afins.

Comment: Na verdade, eu não fiz nenhuma alteração no código em si. Eu conheci o desenvolvedor, que me autorizou a usar e modificar livremente. Minha alteração foi apenas no treinamento do Bot, ampliando o vocabulário dele e agora com a sua ajuda, tentando implementar essa característica. Agradeço demais a sua ajuda. Suas dicas foram tops. Fez toda a diferença na compreensão. Infelizmente, por ser novo no fórum, não me permitem votar ainda. Mas fica registrado aqui o meu voto de agradecimento. Vou continuar no desenvolvimento. Valeu mesmo. Muito obrigado!